# Symfon isnull subquery

Tags: symfony, dql

Trying to check if subquery is null or not and get result. When I try to call `ISNULL` then I am getting error

> Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IS'

but when I call dql in database it works, without error.

Subquery is like:

```
$subQb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('i');
$subQb->select('i.id');
$subQb->andWhere($subQb->expr()->eq('i.id', $qb->getRootAliases()[0].'.id'));
$subQb->andWhere($subQb->expr()->isNull('i.value'));
$subQb->groupBy('i.id');
```

and then I try to use:

```
 $qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->isNull('('.$subQb->getDql().')')
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem using `exists` like: `$qb->expr()->exists($subQb->getDql())`